# Extjs 4 MVC: Enable/Disable Docked Item Button in View Via Controller

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs

I have an MVC app in Extjs 4 which has a View (extending `Ext.panel.Panel`) that contains `dockedItems`:

```
            dockedItems: [{
            dock: 'top',
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            items: [{
                text: 'Check Related Site',
                action: 'viewinrelatedsite',
            }, //...
```

I'm picking up the `action` on this button over in the `control` function in my Controller:

```
    init: function() {
    this.control({
        'statusupdateform button[action=viewinrelatedsite]': {
            click: this.viewInrelatedSite
        }, //...
```

Then of course I have a function in the same Controller which handles the button. I'm using a template in the View, and I have a formatter (also in the View) which tests for whether the field I need is available (`if (!myField)...`), which I *could* use to enable the button.  That part works fine.

What I'm stuck on is how to pass the info about the presence of the field var from the View to the Controller such that the button can be enabled/disabled, and how to pass the contents of this field variable as well.

Thanks very much for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Matt,

You can have a public property inside your view or a public method inside the view which the controller can call on the view reference to inspect/pass the variable value.